# How to fetch data from database in solr

Tags: java, xml, solr

I wanted to fetch data from database for indexing through solr. 
my db-data-config.xml is :

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.9:3306/angara" user="root" password="ampliflex" />
    <document>
                 <entity name="tdiamonds" query="select UID_PK from tdiamonds"
            <field column="UID_PK" name="name" />
          </entity>
    </document> </dataConfig>
```

and i did necessary changes in schema.xml  and solrconfig.xml, but still i am getting some exception. and its not clear to me what it is all about, please give me some suggestion. the exceptions i am geeting are:

> org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException:
>   Exception occurred while initializing
>   context   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.loadDataConfig(DataImporter.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.(DataImporter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.inform(DataImportHandler.java:113)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.inform(SolrResourceLoader.java:486)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:428)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:99)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:594)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1218)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:210)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:929)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:183)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:497)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:115)
>   Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element
>   type "entity" must be followed by
>   either attribute specifications, ">"
>   or "/>".  at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.loadDataConfig(DataImporter.java:178)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "entity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"`

your entity tag is not closed

Comment: Grooveek: Now please help me out..lokk at the my db-data-config.xml  given in question. will it index the tdiamonds tables UID_PK column when i run the command java -Dsolr.solr.home="./example-DIH/solr/" -jar start.jar, it should this but i am not getting any indexes values

Comment: sorry, i'm not a solr expert. Just spotted the typo ... You should ask a new question about this particular problem. This one is closed, I think